# python conflict , how to fix

Tags: python

```bash
python --version

Python 3.10.7
```

and

```bash
python3 --version

Python 3.10.0
```

I want to remove Python 3.10.7, and set python alias to Python 3.10.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messing with the system python on an ubuntu system is a very bad idea.  Multiple parts of the operating system are written in python, and changing this will break anything in your system that uses python.

Instead of replacing the system python, you should install a separate python in another directory (such as /opt) and add that to your local user's path.